# Node file read to default path if i use process.cwd()

Tags: node.js, configuration, path

i have deployed node app on ubuntu server.
but there is a problem, when code executes to read file

```
fs.readFileSync(process.cwd()+"views/....");
```

it tries to read file from "home/ubuntu/views/...."
but my files are not there it should be like: "var/www/mysite/views/..."

please tell me where is the problem and how could i resolve this

Thanks
Ashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.cwd()`returns your *working directory*. You are probably launching your app in your home directory. See this [API doc about it](https://iojs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).

You could:

- integrate something like a `config.json` file that has the full referenced location path to your views. You can `require()`this json file and use the location for your `fs.readFileSync` like: 
  `const config = require('./config.json');
  fs.readFileSync(config.viewLocation + "/nameOfYourView.jade");`
- move your views to another directory (i.e. a express app stores the app views in a folder called "views" in the app folder) (I would recommend this one)
- Add a "hard wired" path in `fs.readFileSync`to your views, if they are always at this location and you are running your app only on this server